# MYSQL - Trigger "END IF" use

Tags: mysql

I have a question, after analyzing and studying just triggers for a while.
I found that some "triggers" end with  **IF END;** and some don't

just above the

**END$$**

**DELIMITER$$**

Is there's a rule? or Depends on the type (*logic*) of trigger we are working in?  (could be counting, updating, deleting, inserting? after, before?

Thank you

Comment: `IF END` is invalid syntax. Do you mean `END IF`? They would end with this if they begin with `IF`, since that's part of the `IF` syntax.

Comment: Is the question whether or not you can use `$$` or `;`?

Comment: It just looks like it if the formatting is wrong and if you have an IF statement in the trigger:   `BEGIN     IF ... END IF      END`

Comment: @Barmar   Thank you
you are right sr.  Know I see why the are ending the code with the END IF:
on the trigger body  it have a  IF.... THEN ... SET ....  and they end with END IF:

Answer (score 0):

If there is a BEGIN there needs to be an END.  But a trigger that is just a single statement doesn't have to have a BEGIN.

Note that the `$$` and `DELIMITER` stuff is not actually part of the definition and is not sent to the mysql server; it is just used by the client to tell where the end of the statement to send is, instead of the normal `;`.

Answer (score 0):

The credit for this answer goes to **[@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)**:

> If they begin with `IF`, since that's part of the `IF` syntax

The ending of the trigger code will end with the `END IF;`.